Proof that a function which is continuous on $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous (Spivak)
I'm following Spivak's Calculus and in an Appendix, the following theorem is being proven:

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

However, I don't understand a few of the points made in this proof, which I'd like to clarify. Firstly, the following lemma has already been proven:
If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$ and is continuous on $[a,c]$, it is uniformly continuous on $[a,c]$
Now, the proof given by Spivak is as follows (paraphrased for convenience)
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, $f$ is $\epsilon$-good if there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall y,z\in[a,b]$, $|y-z| < \delta\implies |f(y) - f(z)| < \epsilon$.
Let $A = \{x:a\leq x\leq b\land f\;\text{is }\epsilon\text{-good on}\;[a,x]\}$. Remember, $\epsilon$ is given to us. So, we first fix $\epsilon$ and then define $A$.
Obviously, $a\in A\implies A\neq\phi$. Also, $b$ is an upper bound for $A$. Thus, $\alpha_\epsilon = sup(A)$ exists.
Suppose $\alpha_\epsilon < b$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it will be continuous on $\alpha_\epsilon$. Thus, there exists a $\delta_0$ such that $|y-\alpha| < \delta_0\implies |f(y) - f(\alpha)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|z-\alpha| < \delta_0\implies |f(z) - f(\alpha)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Hence, $|y - z| < \delta_0\implies |f(y) - f(z)| < \epsilon$. Thus, $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$.
Everything up till here is logical. However, the next point doesn't make sense to me. Spivak comments that "On the other hand, since $\alpha_\epsilon$ is the least upper bound of $A$, it is also clear that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,\alpha-\delta_0]$". Why? This statement is effectively saying that if $\alpha$ is the least upper bound, $\alpha-\delta_0\in A$. But why must this be true? I understand that there must exist an $x\in (\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha)$ such that $x\in A$. Otherwise, $\alpha-\delta_0$ would be a smaller upper bound. But why must $\alpha-\delta_0\in A$?
Secondly, even if we assume this statement to be true, Spivak then says that our previous lemma would indicate that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,a+\delta_0]$. However, shouldn't this instead be true for $[a,\alpha+\delta_0]$? I assume this is a typo.

Yes, you are right, some extra work is needed. The important point is that $A$ turns out to be an interval, so if something is smaller than the least upper bound, then it belongs to $A$.

First of all, yes, the conclusion should be that the lemma allows us to say that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a, \alpha_\epsilon+\delta_0]$, which then contradicts the fact that $\alpha_\epsilon$ is the least upper bound of $A$.

As for your main confusion:
Two facts:

Because $\alpha_\epsilon$ is the least upper bound of $A$, we know that there exists some element $a'\in A$ such that $\alpha_\epsilon-\delta_0 < a'$.
By definition, $x$ is an element of $A$ if and only if $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,x]$.
Therefore, $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a, a']$.
Since $[a,\alpha_\epsilon-\delta_0]$ is a subset of $[a,a']$, $f$ is also $\epsilon$-good on $[a, \alpha_\epsilon-\delta_0]$.

Putting the two together, we conclude that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a, \alpha-\delta_0]$.

In other words, the outline of the proof is:

Define $A$.
Take $\alpha_\epsilon = \sup(A)$
Assume that $\alpha_\epsilon < b$
Conclude that there exists $\delta_0$ such that $\alpha_\epsilon +\delta_0\in A$.
Notice that 4 is a contradiction with 3, conclude 3 is not true.
Conclude that $b\in A$.


$1$ is the least upper bound of the set $A = {0,1}$ but $1-\delta \not\in A$ for $\delta = 1/2$, for example.

@5xum you concluded that because $\alpha$ is the least upper bound, $\alpha-\delta_0\in A$. However, jjagmath is giving a counterexample to that assertion.

What you (and Spivak) are missing is the important observation that $A$ turns out to be an interval (which follows the definition of $\epsilon$-good). Without that the proof is incomplete.

@jjagmath You are correct, thank you! I corrected my proof.

@Aryaan I fixed my proof to exclude that assumption. I made the mistake because the way I usually prove the theorem, I also prove a lemma that $A$ must be an interval.

@5xum makes sense. thanks
